# Trying to saveall() into two separate tables with several entries

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-model

Hey all.  I can't for the life of me seem to get this blasted `saveall()` function to work.  I told it was magical, but I must not have enough midichlorians or whatever fancy stuff it takes to get it sparkin'.

So I've got four different tables--Questions, Comments, Employees, and Answers.  Questions have many answers, and answers have one comment.  Answers belong to Employees.  Here's what's set up in my models:

**Answer Model**

```
var $hasOne = array(
    'Comment' => array(
        'className' => 'Comment',
        'foreignKey' => 'answer_id',
        'conditions' => '',
        'fields' => '',
        'order' => ''
    )
);

var $belongsTo = array(
    'Question' => array(
        'className' => 'Question',
        'foreignKey' => 'question_id',
        'conditions' => '',
        'fields' => '',
        'order' => ''
    ),
    'Employee' => array(
        'className' => 'Employee',
        'foreignKey' => 'employee_id',
        'conditions' => '',
        'fields' => '',
        'order' => ''
    )
);
```

**Comment Model**

```
var $validate = array(
    'answer_id' => array(
        'numeric' => array(
            'rule' => array('numeric'),
        ),
    ),
);

var $belongsTo = array(
    'Answer' => array(
        'className' => 'Answer',
        'foreignKey' => 'answer_id',
        'conditions' => '',
        'fields' => '',
        'order' => ''
    )
);
```

When I run `saveall()` for my data, I'm getting an error saying that my answer_id for my comments are not numeric.  Here's what my data tree is set up like that I'm trying to save (using `$this->Answer->saveall($this->data);`:

```
[Answer] => Array
        (
            [1] => Array
                (
                    [question_id] => 1
                    [employee_id] => 14
                    [result] => 7
                    [unique_hash] => t9279kn7vh
                )

            [3] => Array
                (
                    [question_id] => 3
                    [employee_id] => 14
                    [result] => 6
                    [unique_hash] => t9279kn7vh
                )

            [4] => Array
                (
                    [question_id] => 4
                    [employee_id] => 14
                    [result] => 3
                    [unique_hash] => t9279kn7vh
                )

            [5] => Array
                (
                    [question_id] => 5
                    [employee_id] => 14
                    [result] => 2
                    [unique_hash] => t9279kn7vh
                )

            [6] => Array
                (
                    [question_id] => 6
                    [employee_id] => 14
                    [result] => 7
                    [unique_hash] => t9279kn7vh
                )

        )

    [Comment] => Array
        (
            [1] => Array
                (
                    [user_id] => 14
                    [text] => test1
                )

            [3] => Array
                (
                    [user_id] => 14
                    [text] => test2
                )

            [4] => Array
                (
                    [user_id] => 14
                    [text] => test3
                )

            [5] => Array
                (
                    [user_id] => 14
                    [text] => test4
                )

            [6] => Array
                (
                    [user_id] => 14
                    [text] => test5
                )

        )
```

Can anyone help me figure out what's wrong here?  I appreciate the help.

**EDIT**:  I've updated the $data array to have its keys start at zero with increments of one (i.e., `array(0=>array(),1=>array(),2=>array());` etc.) and this has taken away the validation error, but the data still isn't saving.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this one:

```
$this->Answer->saveall($this->data['Answer']);
$this->Comment->saveall($this->data['Comment']);
```

for some reason, cakephp sometimes don't automatically save all records of related tables even if you defined their relationships. I'm still trying to figure out why.

Comment: Thanks for the help.  This saves them both, but unfortunately the `answer_id` is not automatically set for the comments.  Any idea how to get around this?

Comment: @beanland: Yeah there is a way, but it would usually work if there is only one 'Answer' and hasMany 'Comment'. When you save the 'Answer', you get its id ($this->Answer->id;), then create a loop to save it to each comment ($this->data['Comment']['answer_id']). As you can see, you can't really save multiple answers with multiple comments all at the same time, because we wouldn't really know which comment belongs to which answer.

Answer (score 1):

SaveAll just doesn't save other related tables. We do exactly what you said, we define them ourselves, we even link the id's manually. It's sorta a pain but it's the best option.